# How to turn off text bolding in VS2019 and VS2022 introduced by installation of VS2022?

Tags: visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022

I installed VS2022, I went back ASAP to VS2019 because of annoying font bolding, but then I found out that the text style of VS2019 was also altered.
How can I turn off this text bolding?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You go to `Tools` then `Options` and look under `Environment` then `Fonts and Colors`. You can then reset each setting to the default setting if you wish. What you've experienced is because VS syncs your settings between different instances, including between versions, using your personalization account. I had a similar problem happen when I installed VS2022, with some other settings.